# ElasticSearch : Search json field stored as string as if it were a nested object

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have an ES index with the following object type:

```
 {
    "_index": "my_index",
    "_type": "logs",
    "_id": "150",
    "_score": 18.605173,
    "_source": {
       "APP_ID": "my id",
       "APP_VALUE": "{\"groupIds\":[798,919],\"Name\":\"groupTestRep\",\"User\":\"TEST USER\"}",
       "LAST_MOD_DATE": 1461711863000,
     }
 },
```

Is there a deterministic way to search the APP_VALUE field for exact User or groupdIds. The ideal scenario would be to store the string as a nested object but in my case it isn't possible. SO I was wondering if there is a way to query this string as if it might be a nested object.

Answer (score 0):

The APP_VALUE should be indexed as an Object not string value ie.

"APP_VALUE":{
          "type" : "object",
          "properties" : {
            "groupIds" : {"type" : "long"},
            "Name" : {"type" : "string"},
            "User": {"type": "string"},
            ...
          }

If you absolutely can't do that you could index it as
 "index": "not_analyzed", 
 "position_increment_gap": 100

This could give you what you are expecting; though you may run into issues down the line later if you want to write more unique queries out of that object. Note that this will Index this field, so it is searchable, but index the value exactly as specified.